# Duda clase Scanner en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-util-scanner

Tengo este pequeño codigo. Ocurre que cuando llega la hora de introducir el tercer dato (el nombre), lo salta, es como si se diera automáticamente a enter y no pudiera escribir nada:

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el primer numero: ");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce el segundo numero: ");
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("--------------"); //esto no es mas que decoracion
```

De tal forma que la salida por consola quedaria como algo asi:

```
Introduce el primer numero:    
1
Introduce el segundo numero:    
2
Introduce tu nombre:
-------------
```

No se porque ocurre esto. Es como si se volviera loca la clase Scanner cuando primero le pregunto por int y luego por String. Sabeis que ocurre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que el método `Scanner.nextInt` no consume el último carácter de nueva línea de su entrada y, por lo tanto, esa nueva línea se consume en la siguiente llamada a `Scanner.nextLine`.

Encontrará el mismo comportamiento cuando use `Scanner.nextLine` después de `Scanner.next ()` o cualquier otro método `Scanner.nextFoo` (excepto `nextLine`).

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Introduce el primer numero: ");
int num1 = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Introduce el segundo numero: ");
int num2 = sc.nextInt();
//Se consume la siguiente linea
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre: ");
String nombre = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("--------------");
```

Fuente:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, fue de gran ayuda!. He leido por ahi que para corregirlo también puedes volver a declarar sc = new Scanner(System.in) y entonces si que el programa espera a que introduzcas el dato sin saltar a la siguiente linea. Esto que acabo de explicar es correcto?

Comment: Asi es funciona de manera igual de la forma en que te mostre y declarando  nuevamente `sc = new Scanner(System.in)`.

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambia el

```
String nombre = sc.nextLine();
```

por

```
String nombre = sc.next();
```

Por alguna razón el nextLine() no te deja introducir dicho input.

Por si tienes dudas de las diferencias>

**next()** lee hasta que encuentra un espacio (para de leer en el primer espacio)

**nextLine()** lee toda la línea (para de leer en el salto de línea)