# Java no me respeta el Scanner

Tags: java, netbeans, poo, clase, netbeans-8.2

Estoy teniendo problemas con una programa de java usando clases. El problema radica en que cuando corro el programa se pide nombre, edad y carrera cuando ingreso el nombre todo bien, cuando ingreso la edad y le doy enter para pasar a carrera solo se ejecuta el println pero no se espera a que ingrese el dato sino que se salta al siguiente parametro.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por que se salta y no espera a que le de el dato.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
package compararedades;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author ERICK UNITEC
*/
public class CompararEdades {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    nombre a1 = new nombre();

    edad e0 = new edad();

    carrera c1 = new carrera();

    System.out.println("Bienvenido");



    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del primer alumno");
    String n1 = sc.nextLine();
    a1.nombre1(n1);

    System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del primer alumno");
    int edad1 = sc.nextInt();
    e0.ed1(edad1);

    System.out.println("Ingrese la carrera");
    String carr1 = sc.nextLine();
    c1.establecercarrera1(carr1);

    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del segundo alumno");
    String n2 = sc.next();
    a1.nombre2(n2);

    System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del segundo alumno");
    int edad2 = sc.nextInt();
    e0.ed2(edad2);

    System.out.println("Ingrese la carrera");
    String carr2 = sc.nextLine();
    c1.establecercarrera2(carr2);

    if(e0.Obteneredad1()> e0.Obteneredad2()){

    System.out.printf("La edad de %s es mayor que la de %s",a1.obtenernombre1(),a1.obtenernombre2());

    }

    else{

    System.out.printf("La edad de %s es mayor que la de %s",a1.obtenernombre2(),a1.obtenernombre1());

    }






}
```

}

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Duda clase Scanner en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168563/duda-clase-scanner-en-java)

Comment: en la linea donde solicita *Ingrese el nombre del segundo alumno*  no le ponga como sc.next sino sc.nextLine

Comment: En el sitio puedes encontrar preguntas relacionadas a esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nextLine

Comment: Según mi experiencia usando Scanner es mejor recibir todos los datos como cadenas y convertirlos respectivamente al tipo de dato que debe tener.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que a diferencia de `nextLine()`,  `next(), nextInt(), nextDouble(), nextFloat(), ...` lee el siguiente token pero no consume el caracter de salto de linea `\n` que se genera al presionar ENTER. Por ese motivo, cuando se ingresa `nextLine()` luego de `nextInt()`, `nextLine()` consume el caracter de salto de linea que no fue leido por el `nextInt()` anterior en lugar del valor ingresado:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del primer alumno");
int edad1 = sc.nextInt();
// Al presionar ENTER, nextInt() lee el numero ingresado pero no consume el caracter de salto de linea generado al presionar ENTER
e0.ed1(edad1);

System.out.println("Ingrese la carrera");
String carr1 = sc.nextLine();
// nextLine() no va a leer ningun valor ya que consumio el caracter de salto de linea generado anteriormente.
c1.establecercarrera1(carr1);
```

Posibles soluciones:

1- Consumir el caracter de salto de linea antes de usar nuevamente el Scanner:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del primer alumno");
int edad1 = sc.nextInt();
e0.ed1(edad1);

sc.nextLine();  // Consume el caracter de salto de linea

System.out.println("Ingrese la carrera");
String carr1 = sc.nextLine();
// nextLine() lee el valor ingresado y a diferencia de nextInt(), si consume el caracter de salto de linea
c1.establecercarrera1(carr1);
```

2- Utilizar `nextLine()` para leer el dato ingresado, el cual tambien va a consumir el caracter de salto de linea. Ya que `nextLine()` retorna un `String`, hay que convertirlo al tipo de dato deseado, en este caso `int`:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del primer alumno");
int edad1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); // Lee el valor ingresado y tambien consume el caracter de salto de linea, luego lo convierte a int.
e0.ed1(edad1);

System.out.println("Ingrese la carrera");
String carr1 = sc.nextLine();
c1.establecercarrera1(carr1);
```

Para esta solucion es recomendable hacer la conversion dentro de un bloque `try catch` para controlar posibles errores en la conversion.